# Getting and setting the value of a specific part of a large multi-dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

Say, I have an array FooArray, which consists of arrays consisting of arrays of arrays- etc.

Then I have another variable D, defining in which depth of the array I want to be looking at.

And lastly I have another array nArray of integers, which determine which array in each depth should be dug further into.

(At least, that's the way I tried to approach this)

Now my question is, how would I get/set any index of the array at depth D, in FooArray? For instance, the array may look like this:

```
[FooArray]
 -- [Array]
     -- [Array]
         -- [Array]
         -- [Array]
     -- [Array] <--- With D = 1 and nArray = {0,1,...}, I'd want this array.
         -- [Array]
         -- [Array]
 -- [Array]
     -- [Array]
         -- [Array]
         -- [Array]
     -- [Array]
         -- [Array]
         -- [Array]
```

There's probably a way to do this, but how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you're better off using a [multidimensional array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx):

```
int[, ,] a = new int[2, 2, 3]{
        { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} },
        { {7,8,9}, {10,11,12}  }
};
int x = (int)a.GetValue(0,1,2); // this returns 6

int[] nArray = new int[] { 1, 1, 0 };
x = (int)a.GetValue(nArray); // this returns 10
```

Comment: Aah, I must have missed that functionality. Thanks!